# Phrase or word for "Guarantee with expected verification"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a set of instructions targeted towards a person. Each instruction has to be followed exactly as it is written, without any deviations. The order that the instructions are to be performed in does not matter. I.e. each instruction is independent of the other instructions.

But there is one exception. One of the instructions **can** be skipped completely **if** the person can prove that a certain condition is true. However, I want to make the person certain that not only does this condition have to be true, they should also be ready to provide evidence (to me) that the condition actually is true.

I want to convey that it's not enough for me to get the answer "yes!" to the question "are you sure this condition is true?". I would also require "hard proof" that *undeniably* supports their case.

**Is there a word or succinct phrase to convey this?**

The closest I can come up with is **"verifiably guaranteed"**. But I'm not sure that it makes sense or gets my point across.

For example:

- "If all the shoes you own are verifiably guaranteed to be black, then skip this instruction"
- "You may skip this part if it's verifiably guaranteed that you have two feet"

Comment: The term _verifiable/verified_ embedded within your phrase "verifiably guaranteed" seems to already carry the sense you're after.

Comment: If all the shoes you own are verifiably guaranteed to be black=If all the shoes you own are verifiably black.

Comment: "... are *proven* to be black," or "are *documented as being* black" might work. But it sounds like the conditions are fairly complex, so it might be best to simply use as much language as needed to prevent any misunderstanding: "If all the shoes you own are black, then skip this instruction. Be prepared to support your assertion with evidence."

Comment: Agree with @AndyBonner. The instruction should be to provide the proof.

Comment: I'd say *[provide] [**independently verifiable evidence***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22independently+verifiable+evidence%22) is the boilerplate standard phrasing here. Not quite the same as the much less common [*independently **verified** evidence*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=independently+verifiable+evidence%2Cindependently+verified+evidence&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) that OP seems to want (he takes nothing on trust, but seemingly doesn't want the hassle of having to actually do any verifying himself).

Comment: "You must be able to demonstrate that..." accompanied by a list of acceptable forms of proof. On a practical level it might be simpler to ask them to do the thing anyway rather than complicate instructions.

Comment: I would prefer to use as few words as possible but @AndyBonner's suggestion is easier to read and understand. FumbleFingers' "Independently verifiable evidence" is in essence what I was looking for, but I'm afraid that it'll just confuse my target audience (wasn't obvious to me what it meant at first sight). Thanks for the good suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

"Specific" / "specifically" would be a good words to try.  Or, "only"

Comment: Hi Xavier J. Would you mind elaborating in your answer? If I replace "verifiably guaranteed" in the OP's example with "specific", the result doesn't seem to carry the sense that the OP is after. And replacing it with "specified" pushes the responsibility away from the person who is supposed to follow the instructions, without pulling in the sense of 'proof' that the OP is after.